# C#: trying to add padding to an int in a foreach loop throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string

Trying to accomplish something basic, but I may be attempting a solution in the wrong manner.

I have a DB generate ID. For display purposes they want it to look like this:

```
00001
00002
00003
...
04521
etc
```

So in the page that I am rendering the ID, I am trying to do basic string manipulation (String.PadLeft) and it is giving me a compilation error.

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'string.PadLeft(int, char)'
```

I am going to be honest and say I am not really sure what that error is telling me, other then 'your code won't work this way'

Here is the basic code. It is and ASP.NET MVC4 view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
{
    char pId = Convert.ToChar(item.ProjectId);
    string requestWithPad = String.PadLeft(5, paddingChar: pId);
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(requestWithPad, "Edit", new { id = item.ProjectId }, new { @class = "btn btn-inverse btn-block" })
        </td>
        ....
}
```

I think what I am trying to do is simple enough, I just know I am not doing it in the right place, so where should I do this?

NOTE: I know this is easily accomplished by changing how identity insert works in sql server, for various reasons, this is not an option for me.

Comment: That line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The line with the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are supposed to call PadLeft on an instance of a string:

```
myString.PadLeft(5, pId);
```

You are calling it as if it were a static function of the string class which is no bueno.

Based on your desired output I suspect you want something like this (assuming ProjectId is a string):

```
item.ProjectId.PadLeft(5,'0');
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `PadLeft` is not a static method. You need to call it on an instance of a string.

```
int desiredLength = 6;

foreach(....)
{
    string sID = item.ProjectId.ToString();
    int paddingNeeded = desiredLength-sID.Length;
    if(paddingNeeded > 0)
    {
        sID = sID.PadLeft(paddingNeeded, '0');
    }
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ProjectId is an integer type number and not a string that contains digits, you could just do:

```
string requestWithPad = item.ProjectId.ToString("D5");
```

Of course, you could inline it since it's so simple as well:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ProjectId.ToString("D5"), "Edit", new { id = item.ProjectId }, new { @class = "btn btn-inverse btn-block" })
```